# Group by in python using filter criterea

Tags: python

I have a dataset in which I want to filter out the entities denoted by "Store Number" by whether they were operational throughout the year. I have a month column which has numbers from 1-12 denoting the months of the year.

[image]

For example, in the above dataset, I need to extract Store 457 ONLY as it has all the months from 1-12.

I want to perform the above exercise for two years: 2015 & 2016. My dataset consists for both years.

I use the following code to create new dataframe for 2015 & 2016:

```
iowa15 = iowa[(iowa['year'] == 2015)]
iowa16 = iowa[(iowa['year'] == 2016)]
```

After that I code:

```
iowa15_filter = iowa15.loc[iowa15.groupby('Store Number').month.filter(lambda x: x.nunique()==12).index]
iowa16_filter = iowa16.loc[iowa16.groupby('Store Number').month.filter(lambda x: x.nunique()==12).index]
```

After I run the above, I run:

```
iowa15_filter['Store Number'].nunique() 
iowa16_filter['Store Number'].nunique()
```

For 2016 it is giving me 0 entries. Can someone help what I am doing wrong